# One question about circuit realization of Shor's algorithm in quantum computing

Tags: algorithm, physics, quantum-computing, qiskit

I am studying the quantum circuit realization of Shor's algorithm about factoring 15 into product of prime numbers using the python package Qiskit. See this [website](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/shor.html) for details.

My question is related to the realization of U-gate in this website. In this website, the realization of U-gate is given in the form

```
def c_amod15(a, power):
    """Controlled multiplication by a mod 15"""
    if a not in [2,7,8,11,13]:
        raise ValueError("'a' must be 2,7,8,11 or 13")
    U = QuantumCircuit(4)        
    for iteration in range(power):
        if a in [2,13]:
            U.swap(0,1)
            U.swap(1,2)
            U.swap(2,3)
        if a in [7,8]:
            U.swap(2,3)
            U.swap(1,2)
            U.swap(0,1)
        if a == 11:
            U.swap(1,3)
            U.swap(0,2)
        if a in [7,11,13]:
            for q in range(4):
                U.x(q)
    U = U.to_gate()
    U.name = "%i^%i mod 15" % (a, power)
    c_U = U.control()
    return c_U
```

My question is that why this U-gate is engineered in such way by swapping qbits. How exactly the value of 'a' will affect the swapping scheme? What if I want to factor 33? How should I change this swapping scheme to factor 33?

Comment: The swap operation is the basis for zero-power, reversible computing. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredkin_gate

Answer (score 1):

The value of `a` is part of the phase estimation part of Shor's algorithm, where the operation

```
|y> -> |ay mod N>
```

is applied. So `a` influences the arithmetic operation and depending on how you implement the modular multiplication influences the final circuit differently.

The Qiskit textbook implementation seems to only support special values of `a`, but the software package itself has the general code for all values of `a`: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/main/qiskit/algorithms/factorizers/shor.py

That code uses the Fourier transform to do the multiplication, so `a` will influence the phase shifts applied after the Fourier transform. Qiskit's implementation is based on [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205095) where you can find more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am totally aware of the paper and the websites listed in your answer. I guess my question is why swapping register bits can give us a gate realizing order finding algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

To try and answer your question in the comments:

> I guess my question is why swapping register bits can give us a gate realizing order finding algorithms.

One way to think of Shor's algorithm is it takes as input:

- A circuit* `U`, and
- a starting state `|ψ⟩`

Shor's algorithm tells us the *period* of that circuit, i.e. the number of times you need to repeat `U` to get back to your initial input. We then use a classical algorithm to map factoring to this problem by setting `U|y⟩≡|ay mod N⟩` and `|ψ⟩=|1⟩`.

You can confirm through simulations that the circuit in the Qiskit Textbook has that property, although it doesn't give a method of generating that circuit (I imagine it was educated guessing similar to [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12849/how-to-implement-cx-mod-n-unitary/12861#12861) but you'll need to read [that paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205095) in the other answer for a general method).

If we already know the answer using the algorithm, then we could just find any old circuit with the correct period and plug that in. E.g. a single swap gate acting on `|1⟩` has period 2. Although this doesn't really count as "doing Shor's algorithm", it's often used to demonstrate the algorithm works [1](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-95973-w) [2](https://github.com/qiskit-community/ibm-quantum-challenge-2021/blob/main/solutions%20by%20participants/ex2/ex2-AlbertoMaldonadoRomo-6cnot.ipynb).

---

*To make the algorithm efficient, the input is really "an efficient way to make circuits for `U^(2^x)`". Fortunately, we know how to do this for the circuits needed for factoring, but the Qiskit textbook just repeats `U` inefficiently for sake of demonstration.